# using bit flag in play 2.0 using scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Can anyone please, help me with using flag bits in play 2.0 using scala??

I have 7 options 
checkbox on each byte (
0 - note
1 - testnote
2 - facebook
3 - phone
4 - google
5 - skip
6 - bonus small
7 - bonus big
)

I want to store the database table with column name options(integer).

I have gone through [this](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node13.html#SECTION001321000000000000000)
but I am not still clear how can I do this.
Thanks for the suggestion in advance

Comment: When you get into systems with hundreds of tables and you have small, concise known lists of things that these values will only ever be (or only ever likely to be) this is actually a *reasonable* idea for table compression and data compression. Like all forms of compression there is a price both in and out and if the price is affordable and the tradeoffs worth it then that is each developers call. I wrote a convenience class to handle most of this -- currently I'm adding up the check box values in JavaScript -- I was here looking for an elegant way to do this inside Play's FORM idiom...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are going to have huge number of records, I would avoid to do it that way.
Your approach limits your options by storage (what happens if/when you need to add new set of options...). Verifing your data manually will be more painful. 
Simpler way would be have either one column for each option or if starts not to be feasible (option2) have lookup table with all options one line has.
 In any case, how you store data should be independent and separated of how you use play. To enter or edit data would be variation of contacts demo application...